# Change image using only CSS

Tags: css, theme-customizer, theme-twenty-fifteen

I'm using the twenty fifteen theme.

I have a logo set using the WP Customizer.

I want to have the image change on mobile or tablet view.

The breakpoint is anything smaller than 59.6875em.

I'm using this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 59.6875em) {
  .custom-logo {
    content: url("https://www.example.com/example/wp-content/uploads/Logo_Wide_2x.png");
        width: 300px;
  }
}
```

It works in Chrome but not Firefox.

I've tried adding :before and :after and adding an `a` tag, as suggested on other answers, but none of that works.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong, and how I can get this to work on Firefox?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="site-branding">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/example/aa00/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img src="https://www.example.com/example/aa00/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/04/cropped-Logo_248_2x.png" class="custom-logo" alt="Seed" itemprop="logo" srcset="https://www.example.com/example/aa00/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/04/cropped-Logo_248_2x.png 248w, https://www.example.com/example/aa00/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/04/cropped-Logo_248_2x-150x150.png 150w" sizes="(max-width: 248px) 100vw, 248px" width="248" height="248"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to clear the browser cashe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the URL of the img tag, use your media query to hide the image and change the `:before` of your `<a>`.  Like this...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 59.6875em) {
    .site-branding img {
        display:none;
    }
    .site-branding a::before {
        content: url("https://www.example.com/example/wp-content/uploads/Logo_Wide_2x.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I can't use this code in the Customizer,

<a class="custom-logo" href="#">
    <img class="custom-logo" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
</a>

because it gives an error, saying: Markup is not allowed in CSS.

Comment: That was just an example.  Use whatever wrapper is around the img.  Add your markup to the question.

Comment: I updated my answer since you provided the markup.  tested and works.

Comment: Thank you kindly. It works, but now there seems to be no way to set the width of the replacement image. I've tried adding a width to .custom-logo and to .custom-logo-link and also to .site-branding but the image always shows at full width. In the example shown in the original question, the width value does actually work.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with classes for each screen size and media queries.  I saw this answered on this page originally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984737/display-a-different-logo-on-mobile-and-desktop

```
<style>
/* hide mobile version by default */
.logo .mobile {
display: none;
  }

/* when screen is less than 59.6875em wide
 show mobile version and hide desktop */
@media (max-width: 59.6875em) {
.logo .mobile {
  display: block;
}
.logo .desktop {
  display: none;
}
}
</style>

<div class="logo">
  <img src="/images/logo_desktop.png" class="desktop" />
  <img src="/images/logo_mobile.png" class="mobile />
</div>
```

Comment: Uh no, that works a little bit different. Buzzword `srcset`. See https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/

Comment: leymannx, ok can you please set up the code for the srcset method as a solution to the question above?

Comment: No, as this is nothing WordPress-specific. Apart from that the link already explains it all, no?